# Visual Studio 2022 not recognizing SDK project format

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

My VS 2022 Community Edition seems to not recognize the SDK project file format in a .NET 6 solution which works fine for my team mates. Solution explorer is empty, the existing files get shown only by activating the "Show all files" option. I can "Include in project" them which leads to the class names being included in the csproj file, which should NOT be the case with SDK project files. The csproj file header is (correctly)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting and cloning the repository again, it worked. The solution folder name contained a blank which got replaced by `%20` in the git clone link. When I cloned it for the first time, I didn't replace the %20 for the locally created folder which by default has the same name like in the link.

I would have expected Visual Studio to just scan the current directories for known file types, but obviously it didn't like the main folder to be named like My%20Solution.